# Cannot push to aws ec2 from my local ubuntu machine

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, git-bare

I tried to push to an aws ec2 instance using git but I always get this error :

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to ssh://ubuntu@..../..../myrepo.git
```

what i did:
1- create a git bare repository on my ec2 server (ubuntu 18.04)

```
mkdir myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git init --bare
```

2- in my local machine (ubuntu 16.04):
a- add myserverkey.pem in ~/.ssh/
b- add the following to .ssh/config

```
Host myserver
Hostname myserverpublicdns
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserverkey.pem
```

c- in my project directory I did the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin myserver:/~/path/to/myrepo.git
git add .
git commit -m 'test commit'
git push origin master
```

also, I tried

```
git remote add origin ssh://ubuntu@myserverpublicdns/home/../path/to/myrepo.git
```

and it gives the same error when I push to the server

The error is :

```
Counting objects: 547, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects : 100% (530/530), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to ssh://ubuntu@..../..../myrepo.git
```

and I couldn't find any solution for my case

Notice that my project size is only 4.5mb and I can connect to my server using :

```
ssh myserver
```

which means there are no mistakes in the .ssh/config file

So what is the problem ?? what I am doing wrong ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of myserver in the lines:

```
git remote add origin myserver:/~/path/to/myrepo.git
```

may not work because "myserver" must be resolved by your /etc/hosts file otherwise git won't find your server.

Your ssh command works because your ssh config file does make the link between myserver and the hostname of the instance.

(If you don't want to update your config every time you stop your instance, setup an elastic-ip on your instance)

You should also have a look to folder permission, you are connecting with ubuntu user, make sure it has the proper right on the git repository path.

Do NOT set a 777 right on a folder, never. Instead create a group :

```
groupadd mygitgroup
```

then add the user ubuntu in this group

```
usermod -aG mygitgroup ubuntu
```

set the proper right on the git reposity to the group :

```
chgrp -R mygitgroup /my/git/path
```

remove invalid right

```
chmod 770 /my/git/path
```

Comment: Hello, Also I tried to do the following : 
git remote add origin ssh://ubuntu@serverpublicdns.com/home/.../path/to/myrepo.git 
and it gives the same error !!
@MB81

Comment: the git repo is stored in the /home/ubuntu ? perharps a basic right issue if it is in another user folder ?

Comment: Actually, it is a permission issue on the server and everything goes well when I changed the permission to 777 for myrepo.git. What would be a better practice to do??

Comment: Thanks @MB81 this’s what I was looking for !